# How I connect with Oracle Database in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I want to connect with oracle instead of Microsoft access database.Please help me.This is the code for asp.net.It works fine.

```
       set Con=Server.createobject("ADODB.Connection")
      set Rs=Server.createobject("ADODB.Recordset")
      Con.open "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=c:\test.mdb"
```

Comment: are you sure this is asp.net.

Comment: This looks awfully like Classic ASP. And You can use any ODBC provider in Classic ASP.

Answer (score 1):

You can use oracle client just like Sql client